# How did Iblis tempt Adam in paradise if he had already been banished from it?

Tags: jannah, shaitan, prophet-adam, adam-and-eve

This is my understanding,

- Iblis is banished from paradise after refusing to bow to Adam.
- Iblis tempts Adam in paradise, to lead him astray.

So, how exactly is Iblis tempting Adam (who is in paradise), after he has been banished from paradise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did Iblis seduce Adam to eat from the forbidden tree?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57822/how-did-iblis-seduce-adam-to-eat-from-the-forbidden-tree)

Comment: Yes, thank you.